# Calling a method in another viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a UINavigationController containing a UIViewController with an MKMapView onto which I push a UITableViewController which contains a list of items obtained from Core Data.  Based on the selected item on the table, I want to return to the navigation controller and call a method, passing the object selected in the table.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "return" to a UINavigationController.  That is to say, it has no UIView associated with it.  It is intended to be treated as a way to just keep track of a stack of UIViewControllers.  Since it sounds like this UITableViewController is your root view, there isn't anywhere to "return" back to.  I suggest you simply push another UIViewController in the selectRow: handler that will be able to bring up the view detailing the selected text field.

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I neglected to mention I have a viewController with a map as the root view.  Question amended, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your first UIViewController a delegate of your UITableViewController, and invoke appropriate methods when an object is selected in the table. Something like this:

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectObject:)]) {
    [delegate tableView:self didSelectObject:object];
}
```

Comment: So in the header file of the first UIViewController I'd need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol right?  How would I simultaneously pop the UITableViewController off the UINavigationController stack so my first UIViewController was the one visible when I take action on the object passed back to it?

Comment: Actually you'd create a new delegate for your detailed view controller (DetailedViewControllerDelegate). Before pushing that view controller, you would set `viewController.delegate = self` in the parent view controller. You will then have access to the delegate right from within your detailed view controller.

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://jonmsterling.com/2009/08/01/using-custom-delegates-in-objective-c.html